# How to achieve-If microservice A is unhealthy then how load balancer can send request to healthy microservice B or C using CircuitBreaker?

Tags: java, microservices, load-balancing, circuit-breaker

I am working on Microservices architecture in Spring boot with java, need help with the scenario as below:

How to achieve in Spring boot - If microservice A is unhealthy then how load balancer can send a request to healthy microservice B or C using Circuit Breaker.

I am new to Microservices architecture, please me for this or please share any document which I can refer to for better understanding.

If anyone has any other way to achieve this goal, suggestions, and comments are most welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you correctly.

Your service can be monitored by an orchestrator (e.g. Kubernetes) for instances being healthy/unhealthy. It calls a special endpoint of your service (e.g. spring-boot-actuator -> /actuator/health). If one of two instance is unhealthy and Kubernetes should provide 2 of them, it will destroy the unhealthy and bring up fresh one.

A LoadBalancer themself come with a variety of algorithms to determine what instance gets the client request (e.g. Least Connection, Least Response Time, Round Robin and IP Hash), as part of the product. Your part would be to add instances of your application to the LoadBalancer (depends on your environment).

Circuit Breaker are inside *your* application to handle communication failures between your service and remote services you are consuming. A LoadBalancer could also use this pattern, but as mentioned before it´s up to them.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, can you please me any githube code URL or any code site from there iI can refer for a better understanding

Answer (score -1):

you should use zuul proxy with eureka server
[check this](https://dzone.com/articles/service-discovery-with-eureka-and-zuul)